# Hide play button when video is not autoplaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, video

On my website there is a video which should autoplay. It does that on most devices, apart from, of course, iPhones. I'm using the WordPress cover widget (and WordPress beta 5.5) for the video.

When it doesn't autoplay on the iPhone, it shows an unclickable play button:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO9Ee.png)

How can I make this play button disappear, so that at least a static image shows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to code in `js`(javascript) or knows somebody who does, you could remove the play button icon or even `autoplay` the video for iPhone.

helpful resources
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn
https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

There is this handy npm package that can help its called `react-player` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

it works with vanillajs to check out a fiddle of the example on the homepage
https://jsfiddle.net/o62snj3p/

Comment: I'm using Wordpress. While I can add some javascript, I don't know if I should use a whole library like react for my website.
Also, the video is meant to be just a simple visually appealing background video (hero video) with the video hosted on my own server

Comment: You could use WordPress as a Headless CMS and use React for the frontend you'll have to do extra config to handle the routes Traversy Media has a great video tutorial for explaining how to do this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFNXWinbgro&t=1804s, you can use the react-player library WITHOUT a library like React check out the jsfiddle i did in vanillajs https://jsfiddle.net/o62snj3p/

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code? Videos *should* autoplay on all browsers.  For mobile, you need to add the muted attribute.

Comment: `<div class="wp-block-cover has-background-dim-20 has-background-dim alignfull bigheader" style="background-color:#ff3852;min-height:700px">

<video class="wp-block-cover__video-background" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline="" src="[LINK]"></video><div class="wp-block-cover__inner-container">

<h1 class="has-text-align-center">Wir sind Performance TV!</h1>
</div></div>`

I've read that iPhones in battery saving mode are an exception and you can't make it play for them, no matter how you do it. Somehow, https://www.dcmn.com/ still manages to make it work though...